# How to get a decreasing rental cost based on the number of days

Tags: php, calculation

Is there a fast way to get a decreasing rental cost based on the number of days?

For example:

```
If I rent a car for 1day,  the cost is 100$
If I rent a car for 2days, the cost is 100$ + 70$ = 170$
If I rent a car for 3days, the cost is 100$ + 70$ + 50$ = 220$
If I rent a car for 4days, the cost is 100$ + 70$ + 50$ + 50$ = 270$
If I rent a car for 5days, the cost is 100$ + 70$ + 50$ + 50$ + 50$ = 320$
```

So I need a fast way to get the total cost based on the number of days.
For example:

```
function getcost(days){
   ...
   return $cost;
}

echo getcost(1); // it show 100$
echo getcost(3); // it show 220$
// and so on...
```

Comment: switch statement?

Comment: or, numbered array ($array[1 => 100, 2 => 70, 3 => 50]) - so `function calcPrice($days) {#add up accordingly based on number of days (if above 3 keep @ 50)}`

Comment: So, was this your homework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that from day three all consecutive days cost 50$:

```
function getcost(int $days) {
  return ($days > 1) ? (($days - 2) * 50 + 170) : (($days == 1) ? 100 : 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getcost(days){
    $cost=0;
    for($idx=1;$idx<=$days;$idx++)
     {
       switch($idx)
       {
         case 1:
                 $cost+=100;
                 break;
         case 2:
                 $cost+=70;
                 break;
         default:
                 $cost+=50;
                 break;

       }
     }
  return $cost;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$price = $days * 50 + ($days > 1 ? 70 : 20);
```

If you want to you can put it in a function.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this way-

```
<?php
function getcost($days){
   $array=['base' => 100, 'for_2nd' => 70, 'after_2nd' => 50];       
   if($days==1){
       $cost = $array['base'] * $days;
   }else if($days>=2){
       $cost = $array['base']  + ($days == 2 ? $array['for_2nd'] : $array['for_2nd'] + ($days - 2) * $array['after_2nd']); 
   }
   return $cost.'$';
}

echo getcost(1); // it show 100$
echo getcost(2); // it show 170$
echo getcost(3); // it show 220$
echo getcost(4); // it show 270$
echo getcost(5); // it show 320$
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/h9tF5

Answer (score 0):

If your day rate is based on number of days, then to allow you to have a dynamic rate (perhaps different type of car etc.) then it's best to have some form of array which is passed into the function.  The function then uses this and adds the days up till it the rates run out and adds any remaining days according to the last rate...

```
// Cost for each day
$costs = [100, 70, 50];

function getcost( $costs, $days){
    $totalCost = 0;
    foreach ( $costs as $dayCost )  {
        // Add each cost
        $totalCost += $dayCost;
        // Decrement number of days left and exit if reached 0
        if ( --$days == 0 ) {
            break;
        }
    }
    // If remaining days - add last day cost * number of days
    if ($days > 0 ) {
        $totalCost += ($dayCost*$days);
    }
    return $totalCost;
}

echo getcost($costs, 1); // it show 100$
echo getcost($costs, 3); // it show 220$
echo getcost($costs, 5); // it show 320$
```